# operator $oid not found when querying by objectId

Tags: mongodb

I have a join collection of the format `_id: string, a: ObjectID, b: ObjectID`.
When querying using `.find({a: ObjectId('the object id')})`, everything works fine: I get back the right amount of results.

However, when querying using `.aggregate([ {$match: {a: ObjectId('the object id') } } ])`, I get the following MongoError:

```
Error: command failed: {
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1562938985, 1),
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "unknown operator: $oid",
"code" : 2,
"codeName" : "BadValue",
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1562938985, 1),
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : BinData(0,"rInT5fAfp2nUrPwHxMgtXkZsio4="),
        "keyId" : NumberLong("6703870996123746305")
    }
}
} : aggregate failed
```

even though the query should be exactly equivalent?

I am asking this question because in my actual query, the aggregate is much more complicated. So I copied the whole complicated query into A mongo client (Robo 3T) to execute it there, and then slowly started stripping aggregation stages from it while the error was still showing. Finally, I was left with the simplest aggregation stage, the $match: And yet, I still have this error. I went through the whole collection manually, check with $exists and $type, and every single document in the collection is well-formatted, so I do not understand where this error could be coming from.

Any ideas?

Comment: where are you getting `'the object id'` from? Are you sending as an argument / or request parameter. Also, can you do `console.log(object_id_you_have)`? and show me the result?